# How to adjust JMeter repeat requests?

Tags: jmeter

I'm testing the performance of my website using JMeter.

1000 users were forced to log in sequentially and call the sub-page periodically (using Loop Controller).
The interval for sub-page calls was made to be called every 10 seconds using the Constant Timer.

As 1000 users accessed DB data at the same time every cycle, the CPU load of DB increased by 100%.
Can only 50 out of 1000 logged-in users access the sub-page every second?

Answer (score 0):

You can put the "sub-page" request under a [Throughput Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Throughput_Controller) and specify the desired frequency of the requests execution there:

[image]

More information: [Running JMeter Samplers with Defined Percentage Probability](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/running-jmeter-samplers-defined-percentage-probability)

However you should realize that artificially limiting the load will lead to false positive results so you might want to perform the [query optimization](https://www.sqlshack.com/query-optimization-techniques-in-sql-server-the-basics/) or increase the DB server resources instead